# React-beautiful-dnd - warning : defaultProps will be removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings

I don't understand this warning in my console. Can someone tell me if it's library's problem or if it's an error in my side ?
[Warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfvr1.png)

Here is my code which trigger the warning

I'm using the version 13.1.1

```js
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDrop}>
   <Droppable droppableId="list-container" >
      {(providedA: any) => (
         <div {...providedA.droppableProps} ref={providedA.innerRef}>
            {steps.map((step, index) => {
               return <Draggable  key={step.id} draggableId={step.id.toString()} index={index}>
                  {(provided: any) => (
                     <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.dragHandleProps} {...provided.draggableProps}>
                        <div>{step.title}</div>
                     </div>
                   )}
                </Draggable>
              })}
           {providedA.placeholder}
         </div>
      )}
   </Droppable>
</DragDropContext>
```

Thanks

I tried to remove the code to find that is the Droppable element which cause the issue. I don't find on the github of React-beautiful-dnd any question on this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The warning is caused by the library. Specifically, react-beautiful-dnd uses an old version of react-redux, which in turn uses the feature mentioned in the message: [defaultProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values).

So normally, react-beautiful-dnd would update it's code to use a new version of react-redux, and then you would update to their latest and the problem would go away. However, since react-beautiful-dnd is [no longer being developed](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd#%EF%B8%8F-maintenance--support), it is unlikely that they will do that. This leaves you with a couple options:

1. The code still works, so you could just do nothing. React is warning you that defaultProps will *eventually* stop working, but we're not there yet. The earliest possible release that could break the code is react 19.0.0, but there isn't even a timeline for that release yet.
2. You could switch to a different library than react-beautiful-dnd. Maybe something like [react-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable) would work for you, though i don't know what your needs are
3. You could fork react-beautiful-dnd and modify their code to fix it. Then you'd use the forked version of the code instead of the original.

Comment: Is there not a way to tell react to ignore this warning ?

Comment: @FemiHiro Yeah, it's polluting the console. Did you find a way to shut it up.

Answer (score 10):

Today, I had the exact same issue as you with `react-beautiful-dnd` 13.1.1 in my project until just now. The steps described below fixed it beautifully. I found what is essentially a fork of `react-beautiful-dnd` called [`@hello-pangea/dnd`](https://github.com/hello-pangea/dnd) that provides the exact same functionality of the latest version of `react-beautiful-dnd` but with up-to-date dependencies. You don't even have to bother with changing the component names or implement them any differently or anything: It "just works."

In my case, all I had in my project from `react-beautiful-dnd` was `DragDropContext`, `Draggable`, and `DropResult` in my main component and then a custom helper function that utilized `Droppable` and `DroppableProps` that was defined in a separate component and imported into the main component, so I only needed to update the import statements for two components.

1. Run this in your terminal: `npm install @hello-pangea/dnd` or `yarn add @hello-pangea/dnd`
2. Replace all `import { ... } from "react-beautiful-dnd"` statements across all of your components with `import { ... } from "@hello-pangea/dnd"` statements.